# scikit feature importance selection experiences

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn

Scikit-learn has a mechanism to rank features (classification) using extreme randomized trees.

```
forest = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=250,
                          compute_importances=True,
                          random_state=0)
```

I have a question if this method is doing a "univariate" or "multivariate" feature ranking. Univariate case is where individual features are compared to each other. I would appreciate some clarifications here. Any other parameters that I should try to fiddle? Any experiences and pitfalls with this ranking methhod are also appreciated. 
THe output of this ranking identify feature numbers(5,20,7. I would like to check if the feature number really corresponds to the row in the feature matrix. THat is, the feature number 5 corresponds to the sixth row in the feature matrix (starts with 0).

Comment: Could you explicitly restate what your question is? You are giving a bunch of approximate assertions and it's hard to guess what you actual question is. Also in scikit-learn, the data is shaped `(n_samples, n_features)` so the feature indices are for the columns of the data matrix, not the rows.

Comment: To answer the first question: multivariate.

Comment: Sorry for my confusing question but I am in the process of learning this area and I agree that the quesion was not clear. Thanks anyway for your clarifications.

Comment: Also "Univariate case is where individual features are compared to each other." is not very correct: "univariate" means that features a evaluated independently from one another by estimating their correlation with the target signal. Then feature selection can happen using a fixed threshold (for instance on the p-value of the univariate test) or by taking the top 100 most meaningful features for instance.

For tree models, importance scores are multivariate as they are computed by analyzing the structure of the learned trees. Those tree models non-linear dependencies between features.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert but this is not univariate. In fact the total feature importance is computed from the feature importance of each tree (taking the mean value i think).

For each tree, the importances are computed [from the impurity of the split](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b8bea8e73333b190546ec1b0ef0d95ed776bc411/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L2228).

I used this method and it seems to give good results, better from my point of view than the univariate method. But I don't know any technique to test the results except the knowledge of the dataset.

To order, the feature correctly you should follow [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html#example-ensemble-plot-forest-importances-py) and modify it a bit like so to use `pandas.DataFrame` and their proper column names:

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier

X = pandas.DataFrame(...)
Y = pandas.Series(...)

# Build a forest and compute the feature importances
forest = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=250,
                              random_state=0)

forest.fit(X, y)

feature_importance = forest.feature_importances_
feature_importance = 100.0 * (feature_importance / feature_importance.max())
sorted_idx = np.argsort(feature_importance)[::-1]
print "Feature importance:"
i=1
for f,w in zip(X.columns[sorted_idx], feature_importance[sorted_idx]):
    print "%d) %s : %d" % (i, f, w)
    i+=1
pos = np.arange(sorted_idx.shape[0]) + .5
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
nb_to_display = 30
plt.barh(pos[:nb_to_display], feature_importance[sorted_idx][:nb_to_display], align='center')
plt.yticks(pos[:nb_to_display], X.columns[sorted_idx][:nb_to_display])
plt.xlabel('Relative Importance')
plt.title('Variable Importance')
plt.show()
```